# How to get last logout timestamp from self?

Tags: xmpp

Is it possible for a XMPP client to get a timestamp indicating the last time when he got offline? Something like what's described on [XEP-0012: Last Activity](http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0012.html) (this can't be done using this extension since the user should be offline in order for its last activity to be the offline presence stanza).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do, but it is not possible currently in ejabberd (ejabberd implements the XEP-0012 Last Activity feature requests).